# OpenLayers2 - Get LayerName from GML Response object

Tags: openlayers-2, gml, xml

I am using the `WMGetFeatureInfo` control in OpenLayers to select items from my layers and return GML.

I use this to get an attribute from the GML;

```
 var val = evt.features[0].attributes.UID;
//Where evt is the object returned from "getfeatureinfo" event.
```

But the GML also contains a whole bunch of other good stuff in between the " `wfs:FeatureCollection`", and "`gml:featureMembers`" sections.

How can I iterate through the `wfs:FeatureCollection` or  `gml:featureMembers` because I cannot figure out the syntax.

Also, would it be easier to parse the info I need from the XML that's returned?